# How to scrape webpage with dynamic table into Google Sheets

Tags: api, web-scraping, google-sheets

I have a problem with scraping these data on the table from this webpage https://www1.pttor.com/oilprice-capital.aspx to my Google Sheets.

I've tried to used IMPORTHTML() and IMPORTXML() but it didn't work and I don't know why. Can anyone help me or advice some tools to me, please?

Thank you

Comment: The table value come from Json imported, both methods mentioned by you will return nothing.

Comment: Thank you, Kin Siang. Do you know other way to get the value to the sheets?

Comment: You need to learn Json scrapping in this case, nothing much I can help here, sorry about that.